# VB.NET Read/Write to physical memory RAM

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2005

Does annyone know or can explain me how to write to memory some data and then read it back?

If i have 1GB free of memory i would like to write 100MB to memory some data and then read it back, i searched net for some documentations but cant find nothing, only writing to other process and some stupidities!

Thank you! :)

EDITED:

I mean on physical memory not virtual!

Comment: there is a nice example, http://hcidesign.com/memtest/ this one actualy puts something in memory, try it with 500MB and it acts normaly... app is running normaly no problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) for this kind of thing.

It sounds like you are really interested in a [RamDisk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_disk) - if so look at [ramdisk.sys](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257405).

Comment: yes i tried that, but seams like its writing to virtual memory or some file not in RAM physical memory! :(

Comment: @FeRtoll - that's shouldn't be the case, though it depends on how you have initialized the stream (if you based it on a file, then yes, a file would be used).

Comment: well i tried that on the way you telling but it seams like it dont work, i readed bytes of file of 200 MB and put that in other memory stream and my memory didnt rised and duno how would i read it back then! btw. ram disk is virtual memory!

Comment: @FeRtoll - You can use the different stream methods to read the data after writing it in. Setting `Seek` and using `Read`.

Comment: but physical memory didnt rise those 200MB so its not writing to physical :(

Comment: @FeRtoll - it is entirely possible that the process has enough unused memory _already_ allocated to it so it doesn't need to allocate more.

Comment: @FeRtoll -not sure what a memory testing utility is supposed to tell me.

Comment: well run this little app and run your task manager and start the test with 500MB and you will se how in your task manager physical memory rises so it actualy writes something to memory and then read it back to see if all ok. and it does not block slowdown a app and nothing!

Comment: btw i gaved you vote up because i aprichiate your chatting with me ;)

Comment: @FeRtoll - and how do you know this is using `MemoryStream`? I just don't understand what this has got to do with your issue.

Comment: i dont know if its memory stream, probably isnt! you told me by using memory stream :) well it has to do with my issue i am trying do the same thing write to physical memory and read from memory the thing i writed before! :)

Comment: @FeRtoll - I don't feel I have much more to add to the discussion. MemoryStream will, of course, use virtual memory if physical memory is in use, but if you have enough free memory, that's what will be used. The other option I talked about is using a RamDisk, which is supposed to _reserve_ the physical memory on startup.

Comment: so as your opinion using this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx i can write to physical memory and read it back?

Comment: @FeRtoll - Seeing as that's what it is for, yes.

Comment: well i tried i have 3GB free physical and 3GB in use and i readed file of 500MB and then putted it in memory stream but neighter virtual and physical dont rise and yes i could read it back. what i am trying to do is just a small memory test. Write to memory read it back, write again read again, wait and then again, little app to pump up your memory and check if all ok like a small memory test tool!

Comment: Are you running a 64bit OS? Is the process also 64bit? Did you try watching what the application does using filemon to see if it does write to the filesystem?

Comment: yes i am at win7 x64 and my app is also 64 yes, i didnt try filemon but it writes since i can read it back :( hmmm

Comment: @FeRtoll - I don't understand how you know it writes to the disk. Use filemon to see if your process does indeed write to disk and how much.

Comment: i dont understand you anymore :( what DISK? no flah memory stick, no disk(partition), no file, i need physical memory you know the little cards near your processor... hope we didnt got each other wrong.

Comment: @FeRtoll - The mapping of physical memory and virtual memory is entirely controlled by the OS, as far as .NET is concerned. You _can't_ control that from .NET. That's why I have suggested a RamDisk.

Comment: why not? i had an example in vb6 wich i updated to vb2003 and it was working a small memtest wich was doing that but since my hdd died a year ago and i lost all data i have no more this examples and cant find nothing on internet. :( but i know it worked all fine and how it suposed to! anyway it can be done in c++ and compile and then manipulate that from vb.net :) i just need example because going from 0 would be hard but seams like i will need to! :(

Comment: @FeRtoll - I am afraid my c++ skills are non-existent, but yes, you would need to code something like that in c/c++ and interop with it.

Comment: @FeRtoll - you may be interested in this site, in particular if you know what WinAPI calls you need: http://pinvoke.net/

Comment: well i know for that site but yes i dont know what winapi calls i need :) i found some samples there and on other sites but none seams to be what i need! nm m8 thanks anyway for your big conversation and try of help i aprichiate it ;)

Answer (score 1):

.NET manages your memory handling for you. So all you would need to do is define a variable (try a 100,000,000 elements array of bytes) and it will be stored in the RAM.

Comment: that would kill my app wouldnt it?

Comment: @FeRtoll - no your app should be just fine.

Comment: so you saying about loop wich just puts some bytes in array and thats all? that will kill my app untill its finished even by using application.doevents() and duno i see no good in that, think its not writen in physical

Comment: check out my comment on main question up there plz! :)

Comment: If you're using a managed lang like VB or C#, you really shouldn't normally have to even think about "physical" or "virtual" memory. the system will handle things in generally the best way. If you need to write to specific areas of memory (say to communicate with device or somesuch), well, that's a whole different situation, but it doesn't sound like that's what you're doing. Just writing to memory and reading it back in can be accomplished in many many ways.

Comment: Arrays, the before mentioned memorystream object, lists, dictionaries, etc etc. VB or C# should be able to handle a 100mb read/write cycle without much problem, but, you may want to ask if that's truly what you want to do, or it might be best to break the source data up and read/process it in chunks.